# Method 'Copy' of object 'Shape' failed: Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)'

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am trying to copy and paste a shape between two worksheets.

```vb
ws1.Shapes(1).Copy
ws2.Paste
```

It fails on the `.Copy` line with the error.

> Method 'Copy' of object 'Shape' failed: Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)'

I cannot find **any** reference in the MS documentation for this.

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct shape? For example, a data validation dropdown is part of the shapes collection and you can't copy that.

Comment: @Rory 100% the correct shape - have looped through all shapes and specified using it's name to get the correct index.

Comment: It works perfectly when I use your code in a new workbook

Comment: @GGG yes, when testing in isolation it seems to work, but when part of the whole algorithm it fails.

Comment: @Dean Maybe you can try to add this```Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)``` (wait 5 second) between  `ws1.Shapes(1).Copy` and `ws2.Paste`. I think it is necessary to wait some time for copy. If 5 seconds is not work, try to change to 10 seconds and so on for your testing

Comment: @GGG when I add the `Application.Wait` wrapper it works, but this is not a scalable solution. I am more inclined to understand the error codes so I can get to the root cause.

Comment: @Dean I think the coding is no problem because it works perfectly. I guess a lot of memory being used for copy and paste, so it fails.

Comment: @GGG my system has 24Gb RAM - would the memory limit come from system memory of Excel application memory?

Comment: There is some issue with the clipboard I guess. Refer this [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-vba-flaky-clipboard/3aee03af-b0be-4664-8d17-79e0507210e7) page. When we copy and paste in a loop or one after other VBA needs some time to copy. It can be provided through `Private Declare` and `sleep` method discussed on the page

Comment: @Dean So, lots of suggestions and help provided (including my code solution below). Could you perhaps now tell us if it answered?

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered the same issue. To date, with no apparent no rhyme or reason.
i.e. the code that selects and copies shapes randomly fails with the reported error message.

Able to narrow down some aspects:
a) only seems to happen in windows 10 with office 365 (other systems, not having the issue)
b) if the user restarts their system and runs the same code again, all works fine.

EDIT:
After further testing and research, concluded issue is a totally random failure within Excel.
The same conclusion was reached by GWteB at Mr Excel (Link removed due to advertising saturation).
The notions presented there sort part of issue out. However, there they only experienced paste failures. Whereas I've seen both copy and paste failures.

I've implemented a function (extending on GWteB's thinking) per:

```
Private Function TransferShape(stMT$, ByVal spSp As Shape, ByVal rgSpTarget As Range) As Integer

    Dim inAttempts%, inMaxAttempts%, inErrType%

''' Selection here assumes paste to target range is in the Active sheet
    rgSpTarget.Select 

procRetry: inAttempts = 0: inMaxAttempts = 100
        
    Do: inErrType = 0
    
    ''' Yield to OS occasionally
        If inAttempts Mod 20 = 0 Then DoEvents

    ''' With local error handling: Attempt the copy and paste
    ''' Note: Recording failed to copy as error type 601, and failed to paste as error type 602
    '''       Though not currently acting any differently based on type
        On Error Resume Next: Err.Clear: spSp.Copy
        If Err <> 0 Then
            inErrType = 601
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            If Err <> 0 Then inErrType = 602
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    
    ''' No error type: Exit Do now (all done)
        If inErrType = 0 Then Exit Do
            
    ''' Attempt failed: Increment attempts and try again (until Max Attempts reached).
        inAttempts = inAttempts + 1
    Loop Until inAttempts = inMaxAttempts
    
''' Failed: Prompt user to keep trying or not
    If inErrType Then
        If MsgBox(Buttons:=69, Title:=stMT, Prompt:= _
            "Attempting to copy and paste a picture failed " & inMaxAttempts & " times." & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Shall we try again?") = vbRetry Then GoTo procRetry
    End If

''' DONE: Clear local objects and return Error Type (if any)
    Set spSp = Nothing: Set rgSpTarget = Nothing: TransferShape = inErrType

End Function
```

After implementing the above, all Shape Copy and Paste failures stopped.
 Interestingly, have also not seen max attempts reached. But further testing of that is for another day.